# Return SQL value from two where condition to display in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table which has a `boolean field` scanning.

I want to display the count of Scan done and pending in **C# WinForm**.

I am using stored procedure in SQL.

```
select count(1),sum(pages),count(distinct custId) from TableA where scanning=0 --Pending
select count(1),sum(pages),count(distinct custId) from TableA where scanning=1 --Done
```

Do I need to create two store procedures in SQL or is there a way to get the result from a single stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    PendingCnt = COUNT_BIG(CASE WHEN scanning = 0 THEN 1 END),
    PendingSum = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN scanning = 0 THEN pages END), 0),
    PendingCustID = COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT CASE WHEN scanning = 0 THEN custId END),
    DoneCnt = COUNT_BIG(CASE WHEN scanning = 1 THEN 1 END),
    DoneSum = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN scanning = 1 THEN pages END), 0),
    DoneCustID = COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT CASE WHEN scanning = 1 THEN custId END)
FROM TableA
```

Comment: @Danish_k12 it's very easy. You can use almost all expressions inside aggregate functions. Check my post -  http://blog.devart.com/what-is-faster-inside-stream-aggregate-hash-match.html